# Storing SessionID against Stream in Server Sent Events in ASP.NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, server-sent-events

I am using Server-Sent Events inside API in ASP.Net Framework, I already have sessionId **(**`HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID`**)** in the API Controller Action but I need to access it inside the `OnStreamAvailable` method so I could add it to the Dictionary as a key.

`Index` is the Endpoint, how can I add the sessionId instead of `Guid` to the key of the dictionary???

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
public class SSEController : ApiController
{

    private static readonly uint HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL = 10; //10 seconds

    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<String, StreamWriter> _streams = new ConcurrentDictionary<String, StreamWriter>();
    

    [System.Web.Http.Route("SSE/")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Index(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var sessionId = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
        var response = request.CreateResponse();
        response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
        response.Content = new PushStreamContent(OnStreamAvailable, "text/event-stream");
        return response;
    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("SSE/SendMessage")]
    public void SendMessage(String name)
    {
        var d = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { data = name });
        MessageCallback(d);
    }


    public async Task OnStreamAvailable(Stream stream, HttpContent headers, TransportContext context)
    {
        StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(stream)
        {
            AutoFlush = true
        };

        await streamwriter.WriteLineAsync($"event: info");
        await streamwriter.WriteLineAsync($"data: Connected \n\n");
        await streamwriter.WriteLineAsync();

        _streams.TryAdd(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), streamwriter);


    }

    public static void MessageCallback(String data = "", String EVENT = "message")
    {
        foreach (var keyValuePair in _streams)
        {
            try
            {
                keyValuePair.Value.WriteLine($"event: {EVENT}");
                keyValuePair.Value.WriteLine($"data: {data} \n\n");
                keyValuePair.Value.WriteLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                keyValuePair.Value.Close();
                keyValuePair.Value.Dispose();
                _streams.TryRemove(keyValuePair.Key, out _);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Inject `httpContextAccessor` into the controller and use that go retrieve the session id.

Comment: @RosdiKasim how will that be possible ?
Could you share a code sample, because this is not .Net Core and I don't know how dependency injection work in .Net Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the issue was quite simple, after discussing with a colleague, he suggested that I should declare a non-static global variable, which will be only scoped within the current request, so I could use that variable inside the `OnStreamAvailable` method.

I actually did that and tested it, it works flawlessly!

So here is the solution:

```
    private static readonly uint HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL = 10; //10 seconds
    public static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<String, StreamWriter> _streams = new ConcurrentDictionary<String, StreamWriter>();

    private String sessionIdOfCurrentRequest;


    [System.Web.Http.Route("SSE/")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Index(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        sessionIdOfCurrentRequest = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID.ToString(); 
        var response = request.CreateResponse();
        response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
        response.Content = new PushStreamContent(OnStreamAvailable, "text/event-stream");
        return response;
    }

    public async Task OnStreamAvailable(Stream stream, HttpContent headers, TransportContext context)
    {
        StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(stream)
        {
            AutoFlush = true
        };

        await streamwriter.WriteLineAsync($"event: info");
        await streamwriter.WriteLineAsync($"data: Connected\n\n");
        await streamwriter.WriteLineAsync();

        _streams.TryAdd(sessionIdOfCurrentRequest, streamwriter);


    }
```